# Creating and calling Angular Services

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript, service, components

Good morning, below I made the "if" condition inside ngOnInit in which it solves my problem with routes, in which the user is inside the manage-actives url and if he put a / after and wrote anything, he will be redirected to home.

**manage-actives-crud.components.ts**

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.loading = true;
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {  
            console.log(params);         
            this.mode = params['mode'];
            if (this.mode !== 'create' && this.mode !== 'edit' && this.mode !== 'view') {
                this.router.navigate(['home']);
            }
            this.id = params['id'];
        });
        this.initData();
    }
```

But I need to create a service so I can put it in other components too to make it easier. I started creating in the util.service file, but now how can I make the call into the manage-actives component replacing the if condition in it?

**util.service.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UtilService
{
    public mode: string;

    constructor(
        private router: Router
     ) { }

    public invalidUrl(url: any): void
    {
        if (this.mode !== 'create' && this.mode !== 'edit' && this.mode !== 'view') {
        void this.router.navigate(['home' + url])
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to extract the if statement into a service and then use it within your ngOnInit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I modified the question a little, please check if it is clearer. @Andres2142

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `guard` which validates if someone can navigate into a certain route:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class TheGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
     this.loading = true;
     this.route.params.subscribe(params => {  
         console.log(params);         
         this.mode = params['mode'];

         if (this.mode !== 'create' && 
             this.mode !== 'edit' && 
             this.mode !== 'view') {
             this.router.navigate(['home']);
             return false;
         }
 
         return true;
     });
  }
}
```

And then, in your router module file, use the `guard` in the desired routes, for example:

```js
import { TheGuard } from './guards/the-guard'

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'manages-crud', 
    component: ManageActiveCrudComponent, 
    canActivate: [TheGuard] // you can use multiple guards here, that's why is an array
  },
  {
    path: 'another-component-route',
    component: 'AnotherComponent',
    canActivate: [TheGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], 
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

So if the value returned from `TheGuard` is `true`, then the user is allowed to navigate into that route, otherwise, returns `false` and the guard takes care of redirecting the user to `home` route.